# Mysql WHERE IN Mapping

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in

I have a Mysql query please check below:

```
SELECT `tbl_classSubjects`.`classID` , `tbl_classSubjects`.`sectionID` ,
`tbl_classes`.`name` AS className, `tbl_sections`.`name` AS sectionName
FROM `tbl_classSubjects`
JOIN `tbl_classes` ON `tbl_classSubjects`.`classID` = `tbl_classes`.`classID`
JOIN `tbl_sections` ON `tbl_classSubjects`.`sectionID` = `tbl_sections`.`sectionID`
WHERE `tbl_classes`.`classID` IN ( 24, 24, 27, 28 )
AND tbl_sections.sectionID IN ( 19, 20, 19, 15 )
GROUP BY `tbl_classSubjects`.`classID` , `tbl_classSubjects`.`sectionID`
ORDER BY `className` , `sectionName`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which produce result as:

```
classID sectionID className sectionName
27      19      6th         A

27      20      6th         B

27      15      6th         C

28      19      7th         A

28      20      7th         B

28      15      7th         C

24      19      LKG         A

24      20      LKG         B
```

Which is wrong. I want to mapping

```
WHERE IN ( 24, 24, 27, 28 )
AND tbl_sections.sectionID IN ( 19, 20, 19, 15 )
```

as 24-19, 24-20, 27-19, 28-15 So it produce result as

```
classID sectionID className sectionName
27      19      6th         A

28      15      7th         C

24      19      LKG         A

24      20      LKG         B
```

Comment: why did you double up some numbers in the 2 in () 's

Comment: you are misunderstanding how `in` works. it doesn't match up in the combinations you have in your head. it just says, is it in !

Comment: also you are doing a group by without an aggregate column. which ain't no big deal, but it is forcing DISTINCT which is prob what you want (won't confuse the next programmer looking at it)

Comment: Yes you are right that IN doesn't match up in the combinations but this is what I need actually for appropriate result. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. see 2 answers below

Comment: Thanks Drew, It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for results `WHERE` the `classID` is `IN`, or a member of, the group (24, 24, 27, 28) `AND` the `sectionID` is `IN`, or a member of, the group (19, 20, 19, 5).

All the results in the first table match these two conditions, these conditions are not at all dependent on each other and the repetitions of 24 in the first group and 19 in the second are redundant.

From your description I assume you want the logic:

```
WHERE (classID = 24 AND sectionID = 19)
   OR (classID = 24 AND sectionID = 20)
   OR (classID = 27 AND sectionID = 19)
   OR (classID = 28 AND sectionID = 5)
```

To further demonstrate `IN`, this can be written:

```
WHERE (classID = 24 AND sectionID IN (19,20))
   OR (classID = 27 AND sectionID = 19)
   OR (classID = 28 AND sectionID = 5)
```

Comment: Yes Arth, I would be nice if it working as you demonstrate : WHERE (classID = 24 AND sectionID = 19)
   OR (classID = 24 AND sectionID = 20)
   OR (classID = 27 AND sectionID = 19)
   OR (classID = 28 AND sectionID = 5)